# No output from cout When assertion Fails

Tags: c++

Cout fails to print anything even though it is on a line before the assertion. It behaves so when I compile and run the code through linux shell. But it prints when tried with an online compiler.
ex-

```
for(int i =0;i<n;i++)
 {  std::cout << "should print";
    assert(2==1);
 }
```

I should see "should print" at least once right? And why the different behaviour through online compilers?

Comment: Try with `"should print\n"`.

Comment: works, I infer because of the same reason as the selected answer states, why do online compilers behave differently?

Comment: Some online compilers might buffer the output, while others don't. Both are valid.

Comment: @raultoks I guess it has to do with the console output implementation; the Linux shell behaves in a different way than the online console widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Output from `std::cout` is probably being buffered here. Explicitly emptying the buffer should make it print before the assertion fails. (`std::endl`,`std::flush`, `std::unitbuf` manipulators should do)

```
for(int i =0;i<n;i++)
 {  std::cout << "should print" << std::endl;
    assert(2==1);
 }
```